# django can't create superuser

Tags: python, django, superuser

I want code a blog with Django. Default User model is not suitable for my blog, I want to code my own User.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
from django.db import models

class MyUserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_superuser(self, email, username, password, created_at):
        user = self.create_user(email=email,
            username=username,
            password = password,
            created_at = created_at
            )
        user.is_admin = True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

class MyUser(AbstractBaseUser):
    email = models.EmailField(
        verbose_name = 'email address',
        max_length = 255,
        unique = True,
        )

    username = models.CharField(
        max_length = 100,
        unique = True,
        db_index = True,
        )

    created_at = models.DateField()

    is_active = models.BooleanField(default = True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default = False)

    objects = MyUserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username']

    def get_full_name(self):
        return self.email

    def get_short_name(self):
        return self.username

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.email

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return True

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        return True

    @property
    def is_staff(self):
        return self.is_admin
```

It has a mistake.[image]

I follow the tutorial instructions. I don't know why this problem occurs.

*I post MyUser model, hope can help answer this question.*

What can I do?

Comment: How are you calling the `create_superuser` method?

Comment: With 3 args propably. My guess is you omit `created_at` when you call this method.

Comment: Posting MyUser model will be helpful to answer.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP has lost interest

Comment: I post MyUser model, hope can get answear to question.

Comment: The actual call to `create_superuser()` is not shown in the source listing.

Comment: The cause of this TypeError is that you have not provided enough positional arguments to your call to create_superuser(). 

Can you share the link for the tutorial that you are using ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be constructing an instance of `MyUserManager` and calling its `create_superuser` method with all of the positional arguments.  You are getting the TypeError because the framework is calling `create_superuser` without the appropriate positional arguments.  If you are receiving this error when you run a manage.py task, such as `manage.py createsuperuser` then it's because manage.py is attempting to call `create_superuser` without getting the right number of arguments together.  These arguments are handled by setting the appropriate fields in your `MyUser` object:

**Accounting for the additional arguments in your `create_superuser` method**

```
USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['email', 'created_at']
```

There are other serious problems with your code.
From the ["Customizing Authentication" documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-django-s-default-user) you'll see that you must extend [create_user](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/customizing/#django.contrib.auth.models.CustomUserManager.create_user) and [create_superuser](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/customizing/#django.contrib.auth.models.CustomUserManager.create_superuser)
in both cases, the username_field is the first positional argument and in create_superuser, password is the second positional field.  I have modified your code to include the `create_user` method within the `MyUserManager` class.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
from django.db import models

class MyUserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, username, password, email, created_at):
        """
        Creates and saves a User with the given username, password, email, created_a
        birth and password.
        """
        if not username:
            raise ValueError('Users must have a username')
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('Users must have an email address')

        user = self.model(
            username=username,
            email=self.normalize_email(email),
            created_at=created_at,
        )
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, username, password, email, created_at):
        user = self.create_user(username, password, email, created_at)
        user.is_admin = True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

class MyUser(AbstractBaseUser):
    email = models.EmailField(
        verbose_name = 'email address',
        max_length = 255,
        unique = True,
        )

    username = models.CharField(
        max_length = 100,
        unique = True,
        db_index = True,
        )

    created_at = models.DateField()

    is_active = models.BooleanField(default = True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default = False)

    objects = MyUserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['email', 'created_at']

    def get_full_name(self):
        return self.email

    def get_short_name(self):
        return self.username

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.email

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return True

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        return True

    @property
    def is_staff(self):
        return self.is_admin
```

Finally, you'll have to finish running through the example to get it all wired up appropriately, [follow along with the full example](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/customizing/#a-full-example)